# Prove $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} \lvert f - f(b) \rvert^2 = 0$ for almost every $b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f^2 \rvert < \infty$.
>   Then show for almost every $b \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   $$
> \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} \lvert f - f(b) \rvert^2 = 0
> $$

I think the proof ultimately revolves around using Lebesgue differentiation theorem, which provides us with
$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} \lvert f^2 - f^2(b) \rvert = 0$ for almost every $b$.

However usual manipulations with $\lvert f^2 \rvert - \lvert f^2(b) \rvert \le \lvert f^2 - f^2(b) \rvert$ and $(\lvert f \rvert - \lvert f(b) \rvert)^2 \le \lvert f - f(b) \rvert^2$ don't seem to get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is expand the square in the integrand and apply Lebesgue's Theorem for $f^{2}$ in the first term, for $f$ in the second term. [Union of two sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$ so both terms converge except for $b$ in a set of measure $0$].

Answer (score 0):

Note
$
[f-f(b)]^2=f^2-f^2(b)+2f(b)[f(b)-f]
$